# Is this sentence correct ? "I have got my car working."

Tags: causative-have

Is this sentence correct.And if it is correct, what does it mean?
***I have got my car working.***
I know that the causative form is : have - object - past participle

Comment: It's a very informal way of saying that you have successfully repaired your car.